# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript fails with error "The control must be in the control tree of a page. Parameter name: control"

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a custom web control, basically extending RadTextBox since it doesn't have onBlur() event. I added a script in the .ascx file. I am trying to register the script but it fails. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function handleLostFocus(o) {
        aler(o.toString());
    }
</script>

public partial class MyTextBox : RadTextBox, IScriptControl
{
    private void RegisterScripts()
    {
        try
        {
            String csname1 = "handleLostFocus";
            Type cstype = this.GetType();

            String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, cstype, csname1, cstext1, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        Attributes.Add("padding", "5px");
        Skin = "Office2007";
        Attributes.Add("onBlur", "handleLostFocus(this);");

        RegisterScripts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling RegisterScripts in the constructor of your class. Your control is not yet in the Page in the constructor and hence you cannot register a startup script for a control that's not even on the Page yet.

I suspect the best place to do this would be the Init method. You can do this by replacing the call in your constructor with this:

`Init += (s,e) => { RegisterScripts(); };`

(You could also create a full Init method on your control, but this is the short-hand version)

Comment: Wow, it registers the script now. But it calls the function right away, I need it to be called only onBlur().

Comment: RegisterStartupScript registers a script to be ran at startup... any script registered in this way will run immediately upon the application starting up. The name provided is an identifier used by .NET, not the name of a javascript function to declare. If you want to declare a function named "handleLostFocus" then you need cstext1 to contain the whole function declaration (e.g: `cstext1 = "function handleLostFocus() { alert('Hello World'); }";`)